# Not able to specify window for Tumbling Window trigger dependency in ADFv2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a very simple pipeline that I have setup to test tumbling window trigger dependency. So the pipeline has a single Wait activity. Here is the pipeline code:-

```
    {
    "name": "pl-something",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Wait1",
                "type": "Wait",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "waitTimeInSeconds": 25
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "date_id": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

I have created the following hourly trigger on it which just executes it at hourly intervals:-

```
    {
    "name": "trg-hourly",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "runtimeState": "Started",
        "pipeline": {
            "pipelineReference": {
                "referenceName": "pl-something",
                "type": "PipelineReference"
            },
            "parameters": {
                "date_id": "@formatDateTime(triggerOutputs().windowStartTime, 'yyyyMMddHH')"
            }
        },
        "type": "TumblingWindowTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "frequency": "Hour",
            "interval": 1,
            "startTime": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "delay": "00:00:00",
            "maxConcurrency": 1,
            "retryPolicy": {
                "intervalInSeconds": 30
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter date_id exists so I know exactly which hourly window a trigger instance is running for. Now this executes fine. My goal is to create another trigger on the same pipeline but which will execute as a daily thing and which depends on the hourly trigger. So that unless all the 24 hours in a day are processed , the daily trigger should not run. So in the screenshow below you can see how I am trying to setup this new trigger dependent on the hourly trigger (trg-hourly), but somehow the 'OK' button is not activated whenever I try to specify 24 hours window and you can see the error too that the window size is not valid. There is no json to show , since it's not even allowing me to create the trigger. What's the issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is expecting `1.00:00:00` instead of `0.24:00:00` because there are 24 hours in a day.